# Redirect uri- RequestLibarry-Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I am automating tests with requestlibrary in  robot Framework and I have a question.
The requests that I make are addressed to a server with Aouth 2.0, so the answer brings a "Redirect_URI".
Is it possible in robot framework to go automatically to redirect_URI? or is there a way to load the redirect_uri to see its content?

I had the idea that it is possible to make another request to the url of the redirect_uri passing all the parameters, will this work?

code:

```
${headers}=  Create Dictionary  Accept=application/json  Content-Type=application/json
Create Session  my_session  ${host_${ENV}}  verify=false  disable_warnings=1
${count}=  Get length  ${DATA.DNI}
FOR  ${index}  IN RANGE  ${count}
  ${loginchallenge}=  GET LOGINCHALLENGE  /oauth2/auth  ${strategies[0]}
  ${payload}=  Create Dictionary  credSub=${DATA.DNI[${index}]}  
  varValue=${DATA.SERIAL[${index}]}  acrValue=${strategies[0]} email=example@example.com  loginChallenge=${loginchallenge}
  ${response}=  Post Request  my_session  ${uri}  data=${payload} headers=${headers}  allow_redirects=true
  Run Keyword And Continue On Failure  Should Be True ${response.status_code}==201
  Log To Console  ${response.content}
END
```

The response to the request generated by my tests:

```
{'redirectTo': 'https://host/oauth2/auth?acr_values=[example_acr_values]&client_id=[example_id]&login_verifier=[example_login]&redirect_uri=[example_redirect]&response_type=[example_response_type]&scope=[example_scope], 'b3': [example_b3]}
```

Comment: If you have a set of higher level keywords that do the communication, you can intercept the response and react to the presence of the redirect key in the response, relaying the original request to it (modified it as you need). Without any code of how you tried to do it so far, this is the best (generic and vauge) answer at least I can give. Is it possible? Yes, almost anything is possible in software - in general.

Comment: @TodorMinakov edited

Comment: As highlighted by Todor, this situation benefits from a custom keyword layer, that encapsulated this initial request, plus any redirects, from your test logic. In this case you can check [Dictionary Should Contain Key](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Collections.html#Dictionary%20Should%20Contain%20Key) if the `redirectTo` key is present and then recall the same keyword.

Answer (score 1):

In the RequestLibrary [GitHub Project](https://github.com/MarketSquare/robotframework-requests) [documentation](http://marketsquare.github.io/robotframework-requests/doc/RequestsLibrary.html) for the keyword [Get Request](http://marketsquare.github.io/robotframework-requests/doc/RequestsLibrary.html#Get%20Request) there is a specific parameter `allow_redirects=None` for which the documentation states:

> allow_redirects Boolean. Set to True if POST/PUT/DELETE redirect
> following is allowed.